# How to conceptually compute the max of concurrent request/load an server can serve?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, architecture

During the web application architecture design, I have to conceptually compute how many current client that ONE of my server can serve. Then I can budget it.

So, is there any formula to follow about this ? or, How do you compute this? or, usually, how many concurrent client an httpd/tomcat server can serve ?

Comment: Well, it depends (of course). What happens during a request? What kind of machine is it? What kind of dependencies does your webserver have (other webservices, databases, a file system, etc). The best (and maybe only?) way, is to measure these things. You might assume that it will be able to handle 10-100 requests per second, but the only way to know for sure is to have an environment which mimics your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how well optimized is your own code (memory consumption, simultaneous connections, comet or simple http), there's no fixed rule here.

What people do is : they design their system, then they se what consumes resources and optimize and finally they simulate simultaneous connections while following the health of the server. This is what I saw until now for editor solutions

You can still get an idea of that by allocating the memory you think you will need in your servlet processing and do the test of multiple simultaneous connections on your target machine (or on any machine and specify how could behave a machine that is twice more performant for example).